# Defaultsession for KIE-ServerClient not found

Tags: drools, kie

With KIE BusinessCentral Workbench and KIE-Server (7.6.1 FINAL) running on an external Server in a Docker-Environment, I created a KJAR package and deployed it by using the default artifact-repo settings of the KIE Workbench. I have a default KIE Base named "kieBase1" including a stateful session named "defaultSession". Checking with REST I am able to see Serverstate and available Containers. The desired container is existing.

With my springboot application, using **build.gradle** and the KIE-ServerClient API, I was able to walk my way through instantiating KIEServicesClient which also reflects the availability of Container  (`[KieContainerResource [containerId=esalutebasic_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, releaseId=com.esalute:esalutebasic:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, resolvedReleaseId=com.esalute:esalutebasic:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT, status=STARTED]]`).

BUT ....

I receive the warnings:

```
2023-05-30 19:41:34.075  WARN 19136 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.m.i.embedder.MavenSettings           : Environment variable M2_HOME is not set
2023-05-30 19:41:35.436  WARN 19136 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.maven.integration.MavenRepository    : Unable to resolve artifact: com.esalute:esalutebasic:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

AND ...

... **trying to create a session results returns a Null-Value**.
My code:

```
KieSession ksession = kieContainer.newKieSession("defaultSession");
```

Any hint or idea is welcome since I am absolutely stuck (.. I checked for typos a 100 times ..)